# Check if div already contains a specific item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am building an angular app where a button is supposed to append a blockquote in a div but this should only be possible if the blockquote is not already in the HTML.

Therefore I was thinking of looking for the string `<blockquote id='myBlockquote'>` in the html with the following code but it's not working:

```
if ((myHTML.indexOf('<blockquote id="myBlockquote">') = -1)) {
  myHTML.append('some HTML');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: I would rather overthink your solution and perhaps save the ids in a array in the scope and then look if you already have the id or something like that, much better performance than parsing dom for some id or element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe myHTML is string and not DOM object. You can convert string to html and then find existence of element in it:

```
var elements = $(myHTML);
if(!$('#myBlockquote', elements).length){
   //element does not exists.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking length if your desired element exists or not using `.length` then append

```
if(myHTML.find('#myBlockquote').length > 0) {
  myHTML.append('some HTML');
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying that my html has no method .find
I have use typeof to check the type of my html and it's a string

Comment: You're using a string to finding on i think! but i would suggest you to take object instead of a string!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to don't manipulate the DOM from a controller. This is the responsibility of the view.

You should have an array containing the blockquotes in the scope like:

```
$scope.blockquotes = [{id: 1, text: "This is a blockquote"}, {id: 2, text: "This is a blockquote"}, {id: 3, text: "This is a blockquote"}];
```

And a function that is executed on click that checks if the current user or something has already added a blockquote.

```
$scope.addBlockquote = function(userId) {
  var found = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.blockquotes.length; i++) {
   if ($scope.blockquotes[i].id == userId) {
    found = true;
    break;
   }
  }
}
```

Your view or simply the html template will loop over the blockquotes array and output them like that:

```
<blockquote ng-repeat="quote in blockquotes">{{quote.text}}</blockquote>
```